# Replacement for actiomessages class in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, struts, struts-1

I am trying to update my code from Struts1 to Struts 2 but facing difficulty to update the below code can any one please suggest the replacement for below code.

```
final ActionMessages errors=new ActionMessages();
errors.add("Error Global", new ActionMessage("some_string_in_properties_file"));
sorterrormessage(errors);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending `ActionSupport` provides the `addActionMessage` method. It also provides `getActionMessages` and `setActionMessages` (`Collection<String>`) which would allow sorting them. <sup>1</sup>

The tag library provides `<s:actionmessage />`, when combined with `hasActionMessages` allows checking for, and displaying, the action messages.

To use a property file use an appropriate `getText()` implementation in the action.

---

It would be good to know what difficulties you're actually facing as this is searchable on the web and it's in the S2 docs. A cursory examination of the functionality in `ActionSupport` would probably be a good idea.

---

<sup>1</sup> Sorting messages is only rarely the right thing to do except under very particular circumstances, or if it's explicitly not an alphabetical sort.